# How to get data from `where` query in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not sure what to do with the query object that is returned for `this.actions`

```
this.actionCollection = this.db.collection('actions');
this.actions = this.actionCollection.ref.where('filterId', '==', this.filterId)
```

What am I supposed to do with `this.actions`?  I try to set it as my view but I get this error `Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`

```
<h4>Actions List</h4>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let action of actions | async">
    {{action | json}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call the **[`get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get)** method on it. This will return a value of type **[`firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot)**.

It's essentially a `Promise`, so you can chain the `then` method to it to get the resolved data. Here, give this a try:

```
this.actions = this.actionCollection.ref
  .where('filterId', '==', this.filterId)
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  });
```

Have a look at *[Get multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)* for ref.